# Conditionally Populating a Column with SELECT

Tags: mysql, relational-database, conditional-statements

I have a few tables I want to fetch from my Database and combine them into one result query.

I have a `products` table:

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint(20)                  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| menu_id         | bigint(20)                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| menu_is_section | int(1)                      | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| company_id      | bigint(20)                  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name            | varchar(255)                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description     | mediumtext                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image           | varchar(255)                | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| initial_time    | datetime                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| final_time      | datetime                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| archived        | int(1)                      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| full_image      | varchar(255)                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| kind            | enum('PRODUCT','PROMOTION') | NO   |     | PRODUCT |                |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A `product_likes` table:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| user_id    | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| product_id | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| liked_on   | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

And a `users` table whose only relevant field is `id`

I want to fetch all the products under a menu and determine whether the user "likes" that given product. For that, I was thinking on doing a join to create a new column that will create the column "likes" that will contain a 1 or 0 to see whether the user likes a product or not.

But I am kinda stuck, because I can't find the way to conditionally populate columns with MySQL.

My query so far looks like this:

`"SELECT id, name, description, concat('$image_base_url/products/', image) AS icon, concat('$image_base_url/products_full/', full_image) AS full_image FROM (SELECT * FROM products WHERE menu_id = ? AND menu_is_section = ?) AS selected WHERE UTC_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN initial_time AND final_time ORDER BY initial_time DESC"`

And everything I need to finish it is to find if a user_id likes a product_it, and create the column accordingly.

What's the best way to do this?

EDIT:

I just did a LEFT JOIN and I think I'm getting close to what I want. "liked" returns 1, but I'm 99% certain that's because the user_id is 1. When the user doesn't like a product it returns NULL. I could work with this, but it would be better if my web server returned 1's and 0's.

`"SELECT selected.id, u_likes.user_id AS liked, selected.name, selected.description, concat('$image_base_url/products/', selected.image) AS icon, concat('$image_base_url/products_full/', selected.full_image) AS full_image FROM (SELECT * FROM products WHERE menu_id = ? AND menu_is_section = ?) AS selected LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_likes WHERE user_id = ?) AS u_likes ON selected.id = u_likes.product_id WHERE UTC_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN selected.initial_time AND selected.final_time ORDER BY selected.initial_time DESC"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out. If there are any experts here please review my solution:

`SELECT selected.id, CASE WHEN u_likes.user_id IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE '1' END AS liked, selected.name, selected.description, concat('$image_base_url/products/', selected.image) AS icon, concat('$image_base_url/products_full/', selected.full_image) AS full_image FROM (SELECT * FROM products WHERE menu_id = ? AND menu_is_section = ?) AS selected LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_likes WHERE user_id = ?) AS u_likes ON selected.id = u_likes.product_id WHERE UTC_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN selected.initial_time AND selected.final_time ORDER BY selected.initial_time DESC`

It seems to be properly putting 1 or 0 in a field called "liked". Sadly I can't do much test cases right now but it looks like it's working fine.